# Why is the Gunicorn access log format not working?

Tags: python, json, logging, gunicorn, fastapi

I have a fast API script running with the help of gunicorn, my access and error files are being created, however, I want the logs in JSON format.

I tried passing in the access log format as `"{'remote_ip':'%(h)s','request_id':'%({X-Request-Id}i)s','response_code':'%(s)s','request_method':'%(m)s','request_path':'%(U)s','request_querystring':'%(q)s','request_timetaken':'%(D)s','response_length':'%(B)s'}"` but the logs format is not changing in the file.

**My gunicorn.conf.py file**

```
bind = '0.0.0.0:5000'
worker_class = 'uvicorn.workers.UvicornH11Worker'
loglevel = 'debug'
accesslog = '/var/log/gunicorn/access.log'
acceslogformat ="{'remote_ip':'%(h)s','request_id':'%({X-Request-Id}i)s','response_code':'%(s)s','request_method':'%(m)s','request_path':'%(U)s','request_querystring':'%(q)s','request_timetaken':'%(D)s','response_length':'%(B)s'}"
errorlog =  '/var/log/gunicorn/error.log'
```

**And I am running my application like**
`sudo gunicorn -w 5 --threads 8 -c gunicorn.conf.py main:app`

**This is what my access log file looks like after running the command**

```
<IP>:50506 - "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 200
<IP>:50506 - "GET /openapi.json HTTP/1.1" 200
```

**This is what my error log file looks like**

```
[2022-02-16 18:28:17 +0530] [681146] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  config: gunicorn_htmltopdf.conf.py
  bind: ['0.0.0.0:5000']
  backlog: 2048
  workers: 5
  worker_class: uvicorn.workers.UvicornH11Worker
  threads: 8
  worker_connections: 1000
  max_requests: 0
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  timeout: 30
  graceful_timeout: 30
  keepalive: 2
  limit_request_line: 4094
  limit_request_fields: 100
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  reload: False
  reload_engine: auto
  reload_extra_files: []
  spew: False
  check_config: False
  preload_app: False
  sendfile: None
  reuse_port: False
  chdir: /home/ubuntu/API
  daemon: True
  raw_env: []
  pidfile: None
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  user: 0
  group: 0
  umask: 0
  initgroups: False
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  accesslog: /var/log/gunicorn/access.log
  disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False
  access_log_format: {'remote_ip':'%(h)s','request_id':'%({X-Request-Id}i)s','response_code':'%(s)s','request_method':'%(m)s','request_path':'%(U)s','request_querystring':'%(q)s','request_timetaken':'%(D)s','response_length':'%(B)s'}
  errorlog: /var/log/gunicorn/error.log
  loglevel: debug
  capture_output: False
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  logconfig: None
  logconfig_dict: {}
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog: False
  syslog_prefix: None
  syslog_facility: user
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  statsd_host: None
  dogstatsd_tags:
  statsd_prefix:
  proc_name: None
  default_proc_name: main:app
  pythonpath: None
  paste: None
  on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7fdc4b28b670>
  on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7fdc4b28b790>
  when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7fdc4b28b8b0>
  pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7fdc4b28b9d0>
  post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7fdc4b28baf0>
  post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7fdc4b28bc10>
  worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7fdc4b28bd30>
  worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7fdc4b28be50>
  pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7fdc4b28bf70>
  pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7fdc4b21e0d0>
  post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7fdc4b21e160>
  child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x7fdc4b21e280>
  worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7fdc4b21e3a0>
  nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7fdc4b21e4c0>
  on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7fdc4b21e5e0>
  proxy_protocol: False
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  keyfile: None
  certfile: None
  ssl_version: 2
  cert_reqs: 0
  ca_certs: None
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  ciphers: None
  raw_paste_global_conf: []
  strip_header_spaces: False
[2022-02-16 18:28:17 +0530] [681146] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2022-02-16 18:28:17 +0530] [681146] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2022-02-16 18:28:17 +0530] [681146] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:901 (681146)
[2022-02-16 18:28:17 +0530] [681146] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornH11Worker
[2022-02-16 18:28:17 +0530] [681148] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 681148
[2022-02-16 18:28:17 +0530] [681149] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 681149
[2022-02-16 18:28:17 +0530] [681150] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 681150
[2022-02-16 18:28:17 +0530] [681151] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 681151
[2022-02-16 18:28:17 +0530] [681152] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 681152
[2022-02-16 18:28:17 +0530] [681146] [DEBUG] 5 workers
[2022-02-16 18:28:18 +0530] [681148] [INFO] Started server process [681148]
[2022-02-16 18:28:18 +0530] [681148] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2022-02-16 18:28:18 +0530] [681148] [INFO] Application startup complete.
[2022-02-16 18:28:19 +0530] [681149] [INFO] Started server process [681149]
[2022-02-16 18:28:19 +0530] [681149] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2022-02-16 18:28:19 +0530] [681149] [INFO] Application startup complete.
[2022-02-16 18:28:19 +0530] [681150] [INFO] Started server process [681150]
[2022-02-16 18:28:19 +0530] [681150] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2022-02-16 18:28:19 +0530] [681150] [INFO] Application startup complete.
[2022-02-16 18:28:19 +0530] [681151] [INFO] Started server process [681151]
[2022-02-16 18:28:19 +0530] [681151] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2022-02-16 18:28:19 +0530] [681151] [INFO] Application startup complete.
[2022-02-16 18:28:19 +0530] [681152] [INFO] Started server process [681152]
[2022-02-16 18:28:19 +0530] [681152] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2022-02-16 18:28:19 +0530] [681152] [INFO] Application startup complete.
```

**How Can I get the Gunicorn to input logs as JSON into the file?**

Answer (score 1):

Okay, Turns out I needed to add gunicorn.conf file from this link of [gunicorn's github](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/examples/logging.conf).
And run the following command **`sudo gunicorn -w 5 --threads 8 -c gunicorn.conf.py --log-config gunicorn.conf main:app`**

My gunicorn.conf.py file looks like:

```
bind = '0.0.0.0:901'
worker_class = 'uvicorn.workers.UvicornH11Worker'
```

And I edited the format of log in the gunicorn.conf file to:

```
{Time:[%(asctime)s], Process:[%(process)d], LogLevel:[%(levelname)s], Module:[%(module)s], Message:[%(message)s], PathName:[%(filename)s], ThreadId:[%(thread)d], ThreadName:[%(threadName)s]}
```